# Gradle: replace module dependency with project dependency

Tags: gradle

Using Gradle 1.12, is it possible to create a resolution strategy rule that replaces a module dependency with a project one under certain circumstances?

The reason for this is that we have many projects in the company (dozens), and I don't want to pollute the build scripts with things like:

```groovy
dependencies {
    elastic "company:somelib:1.0.+", "SomeLib"
}
```

Instead i'd like to achieve something along the lines of:

```groovy
dependencies {
    compile "company:somelib:1.0.+"
}

...

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (/* ... Check if project is in build ... */) {
            details.useTarget project(':SomeLib')
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have not been able to replace a module dependency with a project one in a resolution strategy rule. Is there a way to achieve this?

---

**EDIT:** These are things I tried (all resulted in an error):

```groovy
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        if (/* ... Check if project is in build ... */) {
            details.useTarget project(':SomeLib')

            details.useTarget ':SomeLib'

            // Since I noticed this is how actual project dependencies look like
            details.useTarget 'Project:SomeLib:version'

            details.useTarget new DefaultProjectDependency(...)
        }
    }
}
```

---

For future reference, this is the code that I've used in the end. This example implements our very specific flavor of this desired behavior, but others could take it as a starting point and tweak as needed.

```groovy
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    def prjMap = [:]
    allprojects.each { prj ->
        prjMap[prj.archivesBaseName] = prj
    }

    allprojects.each { prj ->
        def replace = []

        prj.configurations.each { conf ->
            conf.dependencies.each { dep ->
                if (dep.group == 'company' && prjMap[dep.name] != null) {
                    replace += [conf: conf.name, dep: dep]
                }
            }
        }

        replace.each { rep ->
            println "Replacing:  $prj.name\t$rep.conf\t$rep.dep.name   ==>>   ${prjMap[rep.dep.name].name}"
            prj.configurations.all*.exclude(group: 'company', module: rep.dep.name)
            rep.dep.properties.excludeRules.each { ex ->
                prj.configurations.all*.exclude(group: ex.group, module: ex.module)
            }
            prj.dependencies.add(rep.conf, prjMap[rep.dep.name])
        }
    }
}
```

Note that while replacing, I used aggressive exclude statements. This is because we have a hellish nightmare of cyclic dependencies and lib projects declaring whole apps as a transitive dep because they need some value class. In a more sane environment, one could simply eliminate the previous dependency entry like so:

```groovy
replace.each { rep ->
    println "Replacing:  $prj.name\t$rep.conf\t$rep.dep.name   ==>>   ${prjMap[rep.dep.name].name}"
    prj.dependencies.remove(rep.dep)
    prj.dependencies.add(rep.conf, prjMap[rep.dep.name])
}
```

Comment: You weren't able? What was the problem?

Comment: Any form of code I tried resulted in an error, and I couldn't find anything in the docs that explains how to do this.

Comment: May You prepare minimal working example? On GH e.g.?

Comment: I've edited with a few examples of things I tried

Comment: I guess nowadays you can do this with https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a resolution strategy cannot do this. It might be possible to implement a solution that, at the end of the configuration phase, iterates over the configurations' dependencies and replaces certain external dependencies with project dependencies. Not sure if it can be done without using Gradle internals, though.